# DevIL image library isn't loading my image

Tags: c++, opengl, image, loading

This is the first time I've had this problem, my code just won't load the images I need it to.

Here is my first function for loading the image into data:

```
    void C_Resource_Loader::v_Create_Image(std::string filename,int nID)
{
    //create image and bind to it
    ilGenImages(1, &image[nID]);
    ilBindImage(image[nID]);

    //check if DevIL successfully loads the image
    success = ilLoadImage(filename.c_str());
    if(success)
    {
        success = ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
        if (!success)
            SDL_Quit();
        //create texture and bind to it
        glGenTextures(nID,&texture[nID]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[nID]);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);


        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP), ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),
        ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT), 0, ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_FORMAT), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        ilGetData());

        ilDeleteImages(nID, &texture[nID]);
    }
}
```

and here is my code for putting the image on the screen:

```
void C_Resource_Loader::v_Apply_Image(int nID, int pn_X, int pn_Y, int pn_Depth)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    //bind the image so it can be textured
    glGenTextures(1,&texture[nID]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[nID]);

    //move the image to the set x and y
    glTranslatef(pn_X,pn_Y,-600);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2i(0,0); 
    glVertex3f(0,0,pn_Depth);
    glTexCoord2i(0,1); 
    glVertex3f(0,32,pn_Depth);
    glTexCoord2i(1,1); 
    glVertex3f(32,32,pn_Depth);
    glTexCoord2i(1,0); 
    glVertex3f(32,0,pn_Depth);

    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Is there a major problem with it, because this code should work, I've used it many times before...

Comment: What is going wrong?  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: the images aren't binding to the quad

Comment: What debugging steps have you taken so far?

Comment: So the quad is just showing up black?  Check for OpenGL errors when you pass the image data and create the quad.  It's possible that you didn't call `ilInit()` before loading the image, and so OpenGL is getting NULL data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `glGenTextures` right before drawing your quad. This should be only called when loading the texture data, since this creates a texture reference in the GPU for use by your code.

And check you are calling `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` somewhere in your code so 2D texturing can be used.